# How to programmatically backup and restore SMS for WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a way to programmatically access SMS stored on your Windows Phone 7 device, using C# want to backup and restore the SMS stored.

Didn't find any API available either for WP7 or WP8.

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to access user's messages, because of privacy issues ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/hh220665(v=VS.105,d=hv.2).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/hh220665%28v=VS.105,d=hv.2%29.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks Piotr for your answer... But i am not sure there must be some trick to backup SMS.